# How to make ASP.NET development server run on port 80?

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on this ASP.NET website project, when I build (Ctrl-F5) Visual studio 2008 runs the website using the ASP.NET development server on port 4730. Is there a  way to make it run it on port 80?

Comment: Following link will be helpful for sure http://withasp.net/specific-port-on-local-host/

Answer (score 9):

Project properties > Web > select Specific Port and fill in `80`

Answer (score 2):

I beleive this is done in the project settings, you can define the parameters to Cassini or have it run on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use command line options to start the webserver on any port you want. Of course , the condition is that the port is available.

http://azamsharp.com/Posts/22_Programmatically_Starting_Web_Server_to_Execute_WatiN_Tests.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project from the Solution Explorer and choose Properties then specify the port "80" and the virtual path e.g:"/mayApp"

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps.

1.) If you already have IIS on your workstation then chances are high that it must be running on port 80. If so is the case with you, then you must first release the port 80 by stopping IIS website service. Refer to the screenshot below.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/iis_stop.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/iis_stop.png)

2.) Now you need to goto Properties' window of your website project in Visual Studio. And set the settings as it look in the screenshot below. And you're done! Hit F5 and see it's running on port 80.

[alt text http://ruchitsurati.net/files/port80_prop.png](http://ruchitsurati.net/files/port80_prop.png)

Thanks.

Comment: would it work on windows vista home basic, it has a limited version of IIS

Answer (score 0):

Select the website in your solution explorer and open the properties window.  Change Use dynamic ports to false and change the port number to 80.  You might have to click away from the site after you change the bool to false and then click back to have the port field become available.